# How to specify in gitlab-ci.yml the memory for a job?

Tags: memory, gitlab, out-of-memory, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a job that requires more memory than the default configuration to compile a large project.
I use hosted shared runners.

Is there a way to specify in gitlab-ci.yml the required memory per job ?

Answer (score 4):

**edit:**

this feature now is available on kubernetes runners: see `..._overwrite_max_allowed` in https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html

**original answer:**

This feature is not currently available, and the development is being tracker in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2902