# How to increase a memory limit in a gitlab.com CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a repository on `gitlab.com` with a CI set up. Unfortunately jobs on the CI have only 4 GB of memory (checked with `cat /proc/meminfo`) and my task requires a bit more than 5, which results in failure.

How to increase the memory limit on the CI?

Comment: Related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60114468/320399

Comment: Unfortunately this question is about self-hosted GitLab. My question is about `gitlab.com`-hosted.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, I've removed the memory-intense part from the CI. I'm assuming that it's not possible, after all you can't really expect many resources from a free service.